# How to loop through all ASP.Net gridview rows and insert to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to loop through all ASP.Net gridview rows and insert them into a database. The code I wrote for these actions is below. But the problem is saving empty data to the database.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    f_name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1"));
    l_name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox2"));
    contacts = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox3"));

    Console.WriteLine(f_name.Text);

    if (f_name != null)
    {
        string query = string.Format("insert into [StudentsData].[dbo].[Student_Info] values('{0}','{1}','{2}')", f_name.Text, l_name.Text, contacts.Text);
        command.CommandText = query;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Label1.Text = f_name.Text.Trim();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You're also just swallowing an exception details that might tell you what's going on. But that sql injection thing is pretty bad.

Comment: can you please clarify why empty data is for you a problem?, I think this is too broad and not enough information question.